# setting the shutdown reason when automating with python and boto3

Tags: boto3

Here is my conondrum in a Amazon Lambda routine I have:

```
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
```

Now does anybody know how to set the shutdown reason for this particular shutdown, so that when the server is started again, the server won't ask me for the reason for the last shutdown. (it reports an error). I have not found any documentation for the Boto3 libraries. Maybe there are som parameters one can pass along the stop_instances method

Comment: You would have to initiate the shutdown from within the operating system running on the server in order to set a shutdown reason. Shutting the server down from the AWS API/boto3 is like walking up to a computer and pressing the power button, there's no method to input a shutdown reason in that scenario.

Comment: The boto script is the on/off button :-) it makes perfectly sense, thanks :-)